# UILabel displaying Unicode Characters

Tags: iphone, unicode, uilabel

I have an NSString that then sets a UILabel.  This contains unicode such as...

> E = MC Hammer\U00ac\U2264

and complete ones such as

> \U2013\U00ee\U2013\U00e6\U2013\U2202\U2013\U220f\U2013\U03c0 \U2013\U00ee\U2013\U220f\U2013\U03c0\U2013\U00aa\U2013\U221e\U2014\U00c5

These are not displaying correctly, is there anything I need to do to parse these at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"U" needs to be a lowercase "u"

Comment: lblResult.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\u2013\u220f\u2013\u03c0 \u2013\u00ee\u2013\u220f\u2013\u03c0\u2013\u00aa\u2013\u221e\u2014\u00c5"];

Comment: btw... i tested and verified that the U in the unicode character string needs to be lowercase.

Comment: The UILabel won't display anything if you are using something like @"\u2013"

Answer (score 0):

What code are you using to set the `NSString`? It's possible that the string is not being initialized properly, and that's having a negative impact on the `UILabel`.

Comment: It is in a subclassed UITableViewCell with UILabels created in IB.

cell.testLabel.text = [Array objectAtIndex:row];

is the code I use to set the text.

Comment: My question has to do more with the array of strings -- how is that array populated?