# How to display Russian Characters properly

Tags: iphone, encoding

I am getting this data

```
\U2013\U00ee\U2013\U00b5\U2014\U00c7\U2014\U00c5\U2013\U222b\U2013\U220f\U2013\U00b5 \U2013\U00f8\U2013\U00b5\U2014\U00c5\U2013\U03a9\U2013\U220f - \U2013\U00f5\U2013\U00ef\U2013\U00ed \U2013\U00f2 \U2013\U00eb\U2013\U2020\U2013\U00ea\U2013\U00ee\U2013\U00fb\U2013\U00eb\U2013\U2020\U2013\U00ef\U2013\U00f4
```

I need to display it. If I display it in a `UILabel`, it displays like:

```
î–µ—Ç—Å–∫–∏–µ –ø–µ—Å–Ω–∏ - –õ–ï–í –ò –ë–†–ê–î–û–ë–†–ï–ô
```

What control will display the characters properly?

Comment: maybe will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294390/showing-asian-unicode-string-in-uilabel

Comment: ahaha

"U" needs to be a lowercase "u"
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329554/uilabel-displaying-unicode-characters

Comment: It looks like a valid result, check it by this command at any browser address bar: `javascript:alert('text that you think is a valid unicode')`

Comment: see my answer, i think your problem solve

Comment: @SAKrisT i am running into this exact same problem, how would one send the data from a server using \u instead of \U? or convert it on the front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is not choosing the right control - any UI control should be able to do that.

I suspect that your issue lies in decoding the above string and assigning it the correct encoding.

Please show us the code that creates the NSString from the above data, I believe in that lies your error.

Also, it appears that your codes are not cyrillic at all. See here for an example of cyrillic letters and their codes (in unicode):

http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-ru.htm

And here's an equivalent output of cyrillic letters:

```
NSString *s = @"\u0414\u0411";
NSLog (@"%@", s);
```

prints: ДБ

Ergo, your own code is correct, but you're not having cyrillic letter codes there.

Answer (score 0):

firstly your Unicode string is wrong (Hint u must small letter)

**use this code**

```
  NSString *str = @ "\u00fb\u2013\u00eb\u2013\u2020\u2013\u00ef\u2013\u00f4";

    const char *getchar = [str UTF8String];
    NSString *getText = [NSString stringWithCString:getchar encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"getText %@", getText);
```

**OutPut**

getText û–ë–†–ï–ô

Comment: That code is needlessly complex. The getchar and getText lines are superfluous. Simply do: NSLog(@"%@", str);